# How to access elements inside <object> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js, svg

My app is split between frontend(**localhost:9000**) and backend(**localhost:8000**). On frontend I use Vue.js and on backend I use Laravel.

What I'm trying to do is get a **.svg** file from backend's public folder and display it in frontend. On frontend I would then access elements(images) inside that .svg file and add a simple drag&drop functionality or change display style on them. The **.svg** files are being created in **Inkscape**.

The problem comes when accessing the elements(images)... I try to access them but it keeps returning an empty array no matter what I do.

HTML code:

```
<object
  id="leftPage"
  title="left page"
  data="http://127.0.0.1:8000/albums/Animals_1/1.svg"
  type="image/svg+xml"
  class="col-6 album-page"
/>
```

Images inside the 1.svg file have all an id that starts with 'image____'.

changePage function that gets called on button press (only prints out elements):

```
const changePage = () => {
  const stickerNodes = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='image']")
  console.log(stickerNodes)
}
```

Output:

[image]

I try running the **querySelector** directly in the console and it doesn't return anything, but when I select an image inside .svg file with a tool inside inspect:

[image]

And then running it again(**querySelector**), then it returns an array of NodeElements:
[image]

Why does it return elements in the console after using **select tool**, but doesn't return them in the function even after using the tool ?

I tried getting document content of the object and then accessing elements inside it as well:

```
const changePage = () => {
  const leftPage = document.getElementById('leftPage')
  const doc = leftPage.contentDocument
  const stickerNodes = doc.querySelectorAll("[id^='image']")
  console.log(stickerNodes)
}
```

But that turned out to not work as well (**error**: *leftPage.contentDocument returns null*)

I read somewhere that it could be a **cors** problem, but I tried putting the .svg files on frontend and accessing it that way and the problem remains...

Maybe I should've stored the .svg files in the  tag instead ? I thought about storing it directly in  tags since that is supported now, but worried about responsiveness...

Maybe the issue could be that I'm exporting .svg files from Inkscape ?

I did some hours of searching and it got me nowhere... While I keep searching I thought about posting it here in case someone knows how to solve this issue...

I hope you could understand most of it and I'm sorry if my english is not that good. If there is any additional information you need, please let me be know. Any help or direction is appreciated ! Thank you.

Comment: It's  o.contentDocument; not o.documentContent(); See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLObjectElement/contentDocument

Comment: Oh my bad. It works now... But It returns null if I try to access the document from my backend... Is there a way to get around the cors policy ?